# Finding the cubic root of a complex number given its relation to the sum of itself and its conjugate

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve for $z$, given that $z^3=z+\bar{z}$.

I tried reducing this seemingly easy equation by rewriting to polar form, completing the square, and some trig manipulation but with no success. How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: What is the sum of a complex number and its conjugate?

Comment: @Kolmo It's $2 \Re(z)$? I can't, however, figure out where to go from there. I made several attempts at it, like I said, with no luck.

Comment: Yes it is. And it is real so $z^3$. now consider Re(z)>0 than what is the argument of z. And if Re(z)<0?

Comment: @Kolmo $\arg{z}$ would be $0$ and $-\pi +2n\pi$. Still no epiphany.

Comment: If Re(z)>0 then it is a complex number with argument 0. So z is a complex with argument 0, 2/3 pi and 4/3 pi. But in the last two cases the cosine is negative so it remains only the first case that gives $z=\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's denote : $z=a+bi$ , then :

$(a+bi)^2(a+bi)=2a \Rightarrow (a^3-3ab^2)+(3a^2b-b^3)i=2a$

So , you should solve following system of equations :

$\begin{cases}
 a^3-3ab^2=2a \\
  3a^2b-b^3=0
 \end{cases}$

Comment: I thought there was a way around this, so as to not to have to expand the $(a+bi)$ binomial (which I mistakenly thought would be a pain), however this seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

A hint: From your equation it follows that $z^3$ is *real*. Now write $z=r\,e^{i\phi}$ and draw your conclusions about possible $\phi$'s and $r$'s. There will be several cases.

Comment: I did write it like that, but I missed the fact that you can figure out $\operatorname{Im} z$ from the argument. Thanks!